# Protect soundsystem from GSM/GPRS pulsing noise sounds

Tags: noise, sound, gsm, pulse, gprs

What is the best way to isolate soundsystem from an modem/cellphone to not hear pulsing noise sounds when GSM/GPRS communication is active.

Comment: Enclose it in a shielded housing so that it sits inside a "Faraday cage" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage  However, some disturbance might still enter via the cables. RF filtering can help here.

Comment: RF filtering is unlikely to help because audible disturbances are by definition in the same frequency range as the sound system signal. Perhaps shielded and/or coax audio cables will help.

Comment: The interference from GSM/GPRS phones is radio frequency, but modulated at frequencies that lie in the audio range.

Comment: Aliasing of a high frequency signal into a low frequency tends to be hard to separate. @nekomatic, can a low pass filter out the aliased signals as well? Never really thought about that.

Comment: RF filtering very much can help. Most audio circuitry gets very non-linear at RF frequencies, acting like the diode in a crystal set to demodulate it to audio frequencies. Stop the RF getting in to kill the problem. The tricky bit is finding where it's getting in : mains and speaker cables (rarely shielded!) can act as pathways as well as inputs. Effective filtering at 800-1800MHz can be tricky too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume by 'soundsystem' you mean either a PA (sound reinforcement) system, or a hi-fi system? The practical answers will depend on exactly what equipment you have but methods could include:

- use [balanced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_audio) audio connections wherever possible
- make sure all cables are correctly shielded and equipment is correctly grounded (earthed)
- make any unbalanced connections, and those with low signal level e.g. microphone or turntable connections, as short as possible
- if the source of interference is typically in one area relative to the sound system, try moving or turning the sound equipment in case this reduces the degree of pickup
- if the equipment has an unshielded (plastic or wooden) enclosure, try replacing it with metal-cased equipment.